# Template parse errors: 'mat-option' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I try to build pop-up form called from material table by button click

Here is my main component code

```
 import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatDialog, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material';
import { PAYMENTS } from "./payments-mock";
import { CourseDialogComponent } from './course-dialog.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-payments',
  templateUrl: './payments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payments.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentsComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
  openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    dialogConfig.data = {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Angular For Beginners'
    };
    this.dialog.open(CourseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CourseDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
        data => console.log("Dialog output:", data)
    );    
}

  //Default values to checkboxes
  pending = false;
  approved = false;
  rejected = false;

  //List of displaying columns
  displayedColumns = ['PaymentDate','Amount','StatusDescription','Reason','Action'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(PAYMENTS);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
     (data, filter: string) => !filter || data.StatusDescription === filter;
  }

  //Methods for checkboxes
  pendingModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Pending' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }

  approvedModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Approved' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }

  rejectedModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Rejected' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }
}
```

And here is dialog component code

```
 import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'course-dialog',
    templateUrl: './course-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./course-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class CourseDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;
    description:string;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CourseDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {

        this.description = data.description;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            description: [this.description, []],
        });
    }

    save() {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

And here is code in app.module.ts file

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CustomMaterialModule} from "./CustomMaterialModule";
import { PaymentsComponent } from './payments/payments.component';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule, MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS} from '@angular/material';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { CourseDialogComponent } from './payments/course-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PaymentsComponent,
    CourseDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CustomMaterialModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS,
      useValue: false
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I try to run app i got this error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'mat-option' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>               formControlName="category">

Where can be my problem?

Comment: post your code where you have mat-option

Comment: You didn't import `MatSelectModule` into your module.

Comment: Seems yes. Thank's it helps! @trichetriche